# How to interpret velocity computation in Particle Swarm Optimization?

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, metaheuristics, genetic-algorithm

Please in PSO metaheuristic when we calculate the velocity what is the advantage of using pBest?[image]

Comment: Hi there, welcome to OR.SE! Please use a descriptive title (e.g. How to interpret velocity computation in Particle Swarm Optimization), and avoid starting your question with 'please'. Have a look at other posts to mimic their style.

Answer (score 0):

In PSO, you maintain a population of candidate solutions. Each candidate solution is referred to as a 'particle'. Particles move around in the search-space based on the formula you defined. A single particle's movement depends on its position and velocity. More precisely, each particle's movement is influenced by its local best known position, but is also guided toward the best known positions in the search-space, which are updated as better positions are found by other particles. This is expected to move the swarm toward the best solutions. (source: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization))

Comment: Thank you for the great explication. So, the velocity depending on the local best-known position?

Comment: and on the global known position, yes.

Comment: and if in the formula to calculate the velocity we replace the pbest by a randomly chosen particle that has sense?